# Whats does "error:Loop must iterate over a collection type" mean in my code?

Tags: apex, soql

```
List<contact> myContact = [SELECT Id,Name,contact.Account.Name,contact.Account.BillingStreet from Contact];

for(contact myCont : myContact)
{
    for(Account acc : myCont.Account)
    {
        System.debug('**** Contact ***** '+myCont);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Loop must iterate over a collection type: Account

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

`myCont.Account` is not a list of Accounts. It actually refers to the account which the contact is related to.

You can iterate the contacts without that second loop:

```
for(contact myCont : myContact)
{
    System.debug('**** Contact ***** '+myCont);
}
```

But you can also access the account's fields (if you query them, of course):

```
for (Contact c : contacts) {
    // print the contact's account's name in the debug log
    System.debug(c.Account.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** updated as per @VigneshwaranG's comment. `Account` in `Contact` object cannot be type casted directly. If you need you can access it's field by correct relationship.

`Contact.Account` is not giving you a collection of `Account` object since it's a look up field in `Contact`.

These are standard fields in salesforce but in case if you are facing a same difficulty with custom fields, just have a look at the object fields in ***Name > Setup*** 
Or have a look at the generated WSDL for the correct field names, types, etc.
[image: contact.Account]

In abouve image you can see `Contact` account field is a lookup field and will give an `Account` object.

Comment: Account myAccount = myCont.Account; this is syntactically wrong as contact lookup to account cannot be type casted to account instance directly.

Comment: Interesting update. First of all, declaring a new variable myAccount and setting it to the value of myCont.Account will compile and run in salesforce. Also, I don't see where a cast was made. Consider the following two lines of code: SObject s = [SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1].Account;
Opportunity o = (Opportunity) s; These produce the following exception message: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Account to Opportunity. This would lead me to believe that the SOQL query is returning an Account, without needing to use APEX to do a type cast. Thoughts?

Comment: You're not casting a "contact lookup" to an Account type.  Apex already returns an Account type for that lookup (as it does proper casting for all relationship lookups).  Account myAccount = myCont.Account; is perfectly legal as it is simply an assignment to a variable of the same type.

Comment: Sorry i wrongly included type casting in my comment. I meant to say it cannot be assigned to account instance. Account myAccount = myCont.Account; system.debug(myAccount); This assignment is syntactically correct and as per @martin it will compile and run in Salesforce. But this gives me null always. Thoughts?

Comment: @VigneshwaranG Make sure to span the relationship in your query. If you use the relationship Account.Id, you should get an Account returned, while using the contact field AccountId would not.

Comment: Account myAccount = myCont.Account.Id; I get 'Illegal assignment from Id to Account'

Comment: @VigneshwaranG Account myAccount =  [SELECT Id, Account.Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1].Account;